# SPFX - cannot get actual label of managed metadata list field

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp

I am using @pnp/sp to get list item data from sharepoint and i am getting list items with managed metadata field and user field. i can get all but not the metadata label which is the one i mainly need. this is my code.

```
return sp.web.lists.getByTitle(masterListName).items.select("Division", "splistname","Id",  "Editors/Title", "Editors/Id", "Editors/EMail")
        .expand("Editors/Id")
        .filter("Editors/Id eq " + currentUser.Id).get().then((userDivision) => {
            console.log(userDivision);
            return userDivision;
        })
```

but this is what i get in return .

[image]

so instead of the label which is supposed to be "Admin" in this case, i get the ID. i have tried the code that koltyakov has written in  https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/139  but when i tried it, i got an error saying TaxonomyHiddenList does not exist. and i am also not sure how to filter using his syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the new `RenderListDataAsStream` endpoint to get the label values.

PnP JS supports this endpoint which can used. Please modify from below sample code:

```
 sp.web.lists.getByTitle(masterListName).renderListDataAsStream({
    RenderOptions: RenderListDataOptions.ListData,
    ViewXml :  `<View>
                    <ViewFields>
                        <FieldRef Name="Division"/>
                        <FieldRef Name="splistname"/>
                        <FieldRef Name="Id"/>
                        <FieldRef Name="Editors"/>
                    </ViewFields>      
                    <Query>
                        <Where>
                          <Eq>
                              <FieldRef Name="Editors" LookupId="TRUE" />
                              <Value Type="Lookup">${currentUser.Id}</Value>
                          </Eq>
                        </Where>
                    </Query>
                </View>`
}).then((userDivision) => {
    console.log(userDivision);
});
```

Also, ensure that you are importing it correctly as:

```
import { sp, RenderListDataParameters } from "@pnp/sp";
```

Reference - [Using the SharePoint RenderListDataAsStream API to fetch lookup and single managed metadata field values](https://www.eliostruyf.com/using-sharepoint-renderlistdataasstream-api-fetch-lookup-single-managed-metadata-field-values/)

[Getting term label values with the SharePoint RenderListDataAsStream API endpoint](https://www.mavention.nl/blogs-cat/getting-term-label-values-with-the-sharepoint-renderlistdataasstream-api-endpoint/)

[Working with list items in REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest)

Comment: thank you! but i am not sure if i am implementing this right because param is returning undefined. "Cannot set property 'RenderOptions' of undefined" i have imported RenderListDataParameters correctly

Comment: my bad, please check edited code

Comment: yes thank thank you! i should read the docs more i apologize THANK YOU!