# Getting error 'response.map is not a function' trying to map a list items with managed metadata fields in spfx react solution

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, react, taxonomyfieldvalue

I am trying to get items from a links list with managed metadata. I am getting an error 'response.map is not a function'. I have used the sample from this answer to get the data using **RenderListDataAsStream** ([SPFX - cannot get actual label of managed metadata list field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/249208/spfx-cannot-get-actual-label-of-managed-metadata-list-field)). I can get the data - I can see it in the console - so I know that the caml query works, but can't seem to map the results. I get the error 'response.map is not a function'.

There is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './LinksWp.module.scss';
import { ILinksWpProps } from './ILinksWpProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import pnp from "sp-pnp-js";
import { ClassListItems } from './ClassListItem';
import { ISPListItem } from './IListItems';
import { sp, RenderListDataParameters, RenderListDataOptions } from '@pnp/sp';

export default class LinksWp extends React.Component<ILinksWpProps, any> {

public constructor(props:ILinksWpProps,any)
{
super(props);
this.state={
items:[]
}
}



  public render(): React.ReactElement<ILinksWpProps> {
    return (
      <div><h1>{this.props.description}</h1>
      <div>{this.state.items.map(function(item:ISPListItem){
      return(
      <div>
       <span><a href={item.URL.Url}>{item.URL.Description}</a></span>
      </div>
    )

})}</div>


      </div>

    );
  }

public componentDidMount(){

  this._getListItems();
}

private _getListItems():void

{


pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Quick Links').renderListDataAsStream({
  RenderOptions: RenderListDataOptions.ListData,
  ViewXml :  `<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Function' />
  <Value Type='TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti'>Group IT</Value></Eq></Where></Query><ViewFields>
  <FieldRef Name='URLwMenu2' /><FieldRef Name='Region' />
  <FieldRef Name='Function' /><FieldRef Name='Geography' />
  </ViewFields><QueryOptions />
  </View>`
}).then
((response)=>{
  console.log(response)
   **let listItemCollection = response.map(item=>new ClassListItems(item));** // this is where I get the error
   this.setState({items: listItemCollection});
  }

)

}
}
```

I have defined an interface and a class for this as well

```
import { ISPListItem } from "./IListItems"

export class ClassListItems {

public URL;
public Region;
public Function;
public Geography;

constructor(item: ISPListItem) {

this.URL = item.URL;
this.Region = item.Region;
this.Function = item.Function;
this.Geography = item.Geography;

}
}

export interface ISPListItem{

URL;
Region : string;
Function : string;
Geography : string;

}
```

Comment: can you change it to `.then
((response: any)=>{
  console.log(response)
   let listItemCollection = response.map(item=>new ClassListItems(item));` and check ?

Comment: That worked so thanks so much. I am now having problems trying to get the value of the url description. The console window shows it to be 'URL.desc' but that's not returning anything. I can display the actual URL but not the description

Comment: in your interface, change the type of `URL` to `any`, i.e `export interface ISPListItem{

URL: any;
Region : string;
Function : string;
Geography : string;
}`

Comment: I have updated the interface but still can't get the description - have tried URL.desc as well as URL.description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out how to do the last bit - to display multi value managed metadata values. I created an additional interface and a class for a label

```
export interface ISPLabel{

    Label : any;
    TermID: any;


    }

export class ClassListItemLabels {

    public Label: any;
    public TermID: any;


    constructor(i: ISPLabel) {

    this.Label = i.Label;
    this.TermID = i.TermID;

    }
    }
```

The I can get the labels out mapping the labels to the interface and class. I think I can use .map() as the property is an array

```
     <div>{
         this.state.items.sort( (a, b) =>{ 
          return a.Desc == b.URL.Desc ? 0 : a.Desc < b.Desc ? -1 : 1;
        })


        .map(function(item:ISPListItem){
      return(
      <div>
        <ul className={styles.myUl}>
          <li className={styles.myUlLi}><a href={item.URL}>{item.Desc}</a></li> 

          <span><ul className={styles.ulLables}>{
            /*  Getting the Labels Out   */
            item.Function1

            .map(function(i:ISPLabel){
     return(
    <li>{i.Label}; </li>

     )
            }

            )
          }</ul></span>
        </ul>

      </div>
    )

})}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, the data returned is in the form of a javascript `object`. Now, we can't use map function over an object, it will only work with arrays. That array is present as `response.Row` in the AJAX response.

So, modify your code as below and then use that to set the state:

```
//code omitted for brevity

}).then
((response: any)=>{
  console.log(response)
   let listItemCollection = response.Row.map(item=>new ClassListItems(item));
   this.setState({items: listItemCollection});
  }

)
```

To get URL description, you should modify the interfaces as below:

```
export interface ISPListItem {

  URL: any;  
  Desc: any;
  Region: string;
  Function: string;
  Geography: string;

}

export class ClassListItems {

  public URL: any;
  public Desc : string
  public Region: string;
  public Function: string;
  public Geography: string;

  constructor(item: ISPListItem) {

    this.URL = item.URL;
    this.Desc = item["URL.desc"];
    this.Region = item.Region;
    this.Function = item.Function;
    this.Geography = item.Geography;

  }
```

Comment: I have updated the interface but still can't get the description - have tried URL.desc as well as URL.description

Comment: Updated the code, please try and let me know. If it helped you fix the issue, you can accept it as answer by ticking the checkbox besides the answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: You will have to change the html to item.URL and item.Desc respectively in the anchor tag

Comment: Great that worked really well thanks! Great Job! One final thing to do is to display the managed metadata fields -  I have tried adding the labels to the interface and class  eg this.CFLabel = item.Function["0"].Label.  This works well but obviously I am only getting the label by referencing the position of the item in an array -  is there another way of doing this?

Comment: I think you need to create another property of type `any` or `array` and then iterate over, will require some trial and error !

Comment: OK. I get how to add a property. But any ideas as to how I would create an array for a managed metadata field?

Comment: would be something like `public Function : Array` and  then iterate over it. Check [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_arrays.htm) and [this link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

Comment: I've tried to do this using old style javascript for(i=0;i<FunctionArray.length;i++)  and I can see the labels in the console window, but its beyond my skill level at the moment how to display them. Do I need to create a new interface and a class for this and then map the property to this or am  missing the point?